# Flickering screen everytime I open a game running with my graphic card?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, display

I have an Nvidia geforce 820m with a 376.54 driver version in an acer laptop but every time I open a 3d game it is flickering so much that it is unplayable also the preview on the control panel is flickering so much. I don't know if this affects but I also have an intel hd graphic card. I tryed updating my drivers but it did not work. Also when I disactivate the Nvidia GPU (and only use the intel) everything is working properly. Any help will be welcome thank you.

This is a preview from my Nvidia control panel :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1McxjzqhTsiSuLZ_sqeDeUZsQ7g8y8bMl/view?usp=sharing

From a game:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fz7MKBaw6xa5t4HI64YSrMuKc-VQttkZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: First try updating the drivers. If the same problem then it's probably hardware.

Comment: I tryed updating the drivers but the problem still exists

Comment: 376 is an old version. Try the recommended 418.81.